# ListBox. Как отключить отрисовку элементов которые полностью не влезли в контрол

Tags: c#, wpf

**(WPF)** Есть ListBox, в нём есть некие объекты. Нужно сделать так что бы те объекты которые не влезают в ListBox полностью - не отображались. Пытался делать через событие изменения размера усекая на нужный размер, но соответственно при вызове изменения размера внутри события, событие вызывается вновь и работает это достаточно криво и дергано. Не смог найти как правильно такое делается. Может есть какое то встроенный парамет, но я не нашел его. Смог родить только такой костыль, но работает он соответственно криво.

```
    private void ManagerControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!changed)
        {
            changed = !changed;
            var a = (ListBox)sender;
            double listheight = e.NewSize.Height;
            if (oldSize != listheight && oldsize2!=listheight)
            {
                oldSize = listheight;
                while (listheight >= 46)
                {
                    listheight -= 46;
                }
                oldsize2 = oldSize + listheight;
            }
            a.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, listheight);
        }
        else changed = !changed;
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33748/discussion-on-question-by-bwehaafox-listbox-----).

Comment: @Stack: Ну да, но всё равно зачем терять там, где можно не терять? Плюс элементы могут быть достаточно сложными. Так что покамест не вижу причины выбрасывать невиртуализированные списки на задворки истории.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:app="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
   ...
```

---

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbt" Height="200" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
   VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Height="33" Background="WhiteSmoke" 
              Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0,-20}}" FontSize="15">
              <TextBlock.Visibility>
                 <MultiBinding Converter="{app:VisibilityConverter}">
                   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}" />
                   <Binding Path="ActualHeight" 
                            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" />
                   <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" 
                            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollViewer}" />
                </MultiBinding>
             </TextBlock.Visibility>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
public class VisibilityConverter : MarkupExtension, IMultiValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          CultureInfo culture) {
        var li = values[0] as FrameworkElement;
        var ah = (double)values[1];        // ScrollViewer.ActualHeight
        var vo = (double)values[2];        // ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset
        var o = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(li);
        var last = (o.Y + li.ActualHeight > ah);
        return last ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, 
                                CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        return this;
    }
}
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]